# how can I add object to array in my react app

Tags: arrays, reactjs, addition, react-props

I am learning React and trying to create a memory game app, in my Card component of the app, if I click on a card, I want to push that card to an empty array. but the array does not save the first card if I click the second card or it does not save correctly because the value of props change every time I click a new card. I checked some of the similar questions but the problems they posted are different.

```
import React from 'react';
import '../memoryGameStyle/card.css';

class Card extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={card:'' }
    }
    onCardClick=()=>{
        const array=[]
        const newCard={...this.props.card,show:true}
        this.setState({card:newCard})
    }
    render(){...}
}

export default Card
```

I am trying to push new cards to array in onCardClick. I have two props, one will show the card I click and the other will show the array of all the cards. I tried to use filter(), push(), spread operator, non work so far, I must have done something wrong. please help, thanks

Comment: you are overwriting the card variable in your state. how will it save

Comment: props should not change. what does this.props.card contain?

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier, card props contains color of the card, show and match status, and id. the color is generated randomly in another component, I will use show and match to check if the card show be shown or hidden

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier I have another props.cards that contains all the cards, I can change card status using this.setState({card:{...newCard,show:true}}). but the problem is still the same

Answer (score 0):

you are over writing the card variable in your state. do this instead

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={card:[] }
}
```

disclaimer: the below solution assumes that newCard contains the selected card

```
onCardClick=()=>{
    const {card} =this.state;
    const newCard= //get selected card
    card.push(newCard);
    this.setState({card:newCard})
}
```

Comment: I am trying that but after I click the second time I got 'card.push is not a function' error, also I am trying to push card to an empty array in my onCardClick, it did not work when I use push

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, You have 2 requirements:

- Show the current clicked card.
- Show all the the cards user clicked in the past. `//Let me know if that's not the case`

Here is what you can do assuming you want to do above 2 things:

```
state = {
  cards: [],
  showAllClickedCards: true 
}
//"cards" holds the cards clicked by the user
//The most recent clicked card will be at the last in the the array.
//You can toggle "showAllClickedCards" to either show all cards or selected one
```

Now here is you can do in onCardClick

```
//Assuming the function is being passed the selectedCard
onCardClick = (selectedCard) => {
     //Do something with selected card
     this.setState(prevState => ({
        cards: [...prevState.cards, selectedCard]
     }))
}
```

Notes: To show the current clicked card you can do `this.state.cards[this.state.cards.length - 1]` .
Hope this helps

Comment: Sure, Keep me posted if you face any issues

Comment: here is what happened, when I clicked once on a card, the array updated correctly, when I clicked again on the same card, the array added the same card which is good. But if I click on another card, the array will update to that card and does not keep the first card so I had a new array with a new card

Comment: Can you share your code via gist? 
I might be able to help you debug.

Comment: @Nhat Any luck... The code above appends the new card into array, retaining the older ones. I am not sure what's happening with your code and will be able to help you if you share your code.

Comment: thank you, I gave up on that and tried another approach to make my app work. I haven't used github, and this app is a practice for my main app. I know it is weird but I will use github after my main app is done.

Comment: All the best @Nhat